# 条件分岐のない？if文の挙動について

Tags: python

下記はテキストを整形するメソッドを定義したものですが、
if文の条件文がelementという変数名のみとなっており、elifやelseifが存在しません。

この場合、if文による条件分岐の処理の流れはどのようなものになるのでしょうか？

```py
def strip_person(element):
    if element:
        return element.replace('人', '')
    return element
```

Comment: "if 文のみ" で elif や else を書かないコードも割りと一般的ですが、このような記述についてもよく分からない…という質問であっていますか？

Comment: はい。論理演算子、比較演算子などがあるif文はよくわかるのですが、それらを用いない条件式の記述について説明したものがあまり見つからなかったので
質問させていただきました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

論理演算子、比較演算子は「演算子」というように、計算して値を返すものです。

例えば`and`演算子は

> 式 x and y は、まず x を評価します; x が偽なら x の値を返します; それ以外の場合には、 y の値を評価し、その結果を返します。

[6. 式 (expression) — Python 3.10.6 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

if文の

```
if [cond.] :
```

の[cond.]部は論理演算子や比較演算子を使った式がよく使われているだけで、
実際には式を評価した値を見ています。

というわけで

```
if element:
```

は`element`が真かどうかみています。

Pythonにおいて何を真、偽と扱うかはこちら

> ブール演算のコンテキストや、式が制御フローの文で使われる際には、次の値は偽だと解釈されます: False 、 None 、すべての型における数値の 0、空の文字列、空のコンテナ (文字列、タプル、リスト、辞書、集合、凍結集合など)。 それ以外の値は真だと解釈されます。

[6. 式 (expression) — Python 3.9.12 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.9/reference/expressions.html#booleans)

Answer (score 1):

elementが空文字であればif文の下の文は実行されず、
一番下のreturn elementが実行されます。
elementが空文字で無ければreturn element.replace('人', '')が
実行されます。
つまりelementが空文字で無ければ'人'が''に変換されますので、
'人'の文字を消していることになります。